# How to replace text "\"" with """ in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have text `03=\"\"` and where want to replace `\"` with `"`
In fact, the above given text is received from xml file where actual encrypted text is `03=""` but while execution became `03=\"\"` so getting an exception. Is there any way to unescape this addition as Regex.Unescape() didn't work? For e.g. XMLFile1.xml

```
<Sample><Demo>03=""</Demo></Sample>
```

I want to decrypt this value of  through below code

```
var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");
var result = doc.Element("sample").Element("demo").Value);    
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(rsaKey);
//Value of result is having additional backspaces as mentioned so decryption failed
var decryptedRSA = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(result.ReplaceBackSlashOccurences()), false);
var originalResult = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(decryptedRSA);
```

Comment: If the XML file when you open it with something like notepad doesn't have backslashes in the text, then it doesn't when you read it into C#. You must be doing something to add them somewhere in your code. Have you made absolutely certain that you're not getting confused about how the debugger displays strings?

Comment: I've already checked & no changes are made to value. Bu, in execution its adding so decryption code is not working. I'm not confused on string behabior in debugger view but the whole value getting changed.

Comment: Well, please provide a [mcve] and we can reopen your question.

Comment: @John, I've updated code in the question to reproduce my issue.

Comment: "Value of result is having additional backspaces as mentioned" - how are you observing that? (I assume you mean backslashes rather than backspaces btw.) I *strongly* suspect you're observing it in the debugger, which escapes quotes for you. Try printing the text to the console instead, and I suspect you'll see there are no backslashes. As a side note, I would strongly encourage you *not* to use `Encoding.Default`. It's almost never the right thing to use.

Comment: Agree, I understood your point. But, my point is variable should its actual value only when it is passed to decrypt function. If this is the behavior then function call should not be failed.

Comment: _"my point is variable should its actual value only"_ - why do you think it has some other value? Perhaps you could add a screenshot of where you're seeing this.